# Creating files in synced location too slow

Tags: vba, sharepoint, onedrive

I have a multitude of macros breaking down information into multiple files, e.g. for each row, create a separate worksheet; or for each row, create a .docx and a .pdf document.

Now to test these macros, I always need to move outside my folders synced to OneDrive/Sharepoint because whenever a new file is created in a synced location, Office takes its damned time to do some stuff related to the synchronisation, thus considerably slowing down the macro execution.

This is equally, or even moreso a problem in production where the macro is run on a much larger sample and by other users, so I have to train them to move the file outside of the shared location (dedicated to collaboration) to their own drive.

Is there a way to defer these actions after the macro execution (besides disabling OneDrive app)? This is causing me issues with development as I am used to the file being autosaved and to having my own version control. This is equally important during the testing, when I change a lot of the code.

Comment: For development work you can switch your file "save/create" location(s) to a local drive outside of OneDrive: you can manage this using a DEBUG constant or similar.

Comment: @Tim Williams My bad, this is of course a problem also in production. I will modify the question.

Comment: Can your macro auto-choose a location (eg user's temp folder) to use as a "scratch" folder?

Comment: @TimWilliams, sure I can do all that but it is very impractical (so it defeats the purpose). I would need to tell the users where to find the documents, plus if it is Temp or Documents or any other obvious choice, the result may get mixed up with other files, or in the worst case, even overwrite something.